# How can I inherit from a class which takes in DI services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns, crud

I want to follow SOLID and have thus decided to make a generic repository that encapsulates 90% of CRUD use cases. Since I will also need more customized queries, I want to inherit from this generic repository in each of my table-specific repositories and add those customized methods there. A big problem I see here is that I will have to pass the inherited class' constructor parameters manually using `base()` and therefore every child class will have to know about its parent's dependencies.

This is my generic repository:

```
public class GeneralRepository<T> : IGeneralRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly string _tableName;

    public GeneralRepository(IConfiguration config, string tableName)
    {
        _config = config;
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public async Task<OperationResult<T>> InsertModelAndReturnAsync<T>(string storedProcedure, T parameters)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

        try
        {
            var result = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return OperationResult<T>.Success(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return OperationResult<T>.Failure("No records created.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return OperationResult<T>.Failure($"An error has occured: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task<OperationResult<T>> DeleteModelAndReturnAsync<T>(string storedProcedure, int id)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

        try
        {
            var result = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(storedProcedure, new { Id = id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return OperationResult<T>.Success(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return OperationResult<T>.Failure("No records deleted.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return OperationResult<T>.Failure($"An error has occured: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task<OperationResult<T>> UpdateModelAndReturnAsync<T>(string storedProcedure, T parameters)
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

        try
        {
            var result = await connection.QueryFirstAsync<T>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return OperationResult<T>.Success(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return OperationResult<T>.Failure($"An error has occured: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

            var parameters = new { TableName = _tableName };

            var query = """
                SELECT *
                FROM @TableName
                """;

            var result = (await connection.QueryAsync<T>(query, parameters)).ToList();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync<T>(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

            var parameters = new { TableName = _tableName, Id = id };

            var query = """
                SELECT *
                FROM @TableName
                WHERE Id = @Id
                """;

            T? result = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(query, parameters);

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a class where I would be inheriting these methods:

```
public class TaskRepository : GeneralRepository<TaskModel>
{
    public const string TableName = "Task";

    public TaskRepository(IConfiguration config) : base(config, TableName)
    {

    }

    // Other table-specific methods here ...

}
```

I chose inheritance over simply injecting an instance of the generic repository because I do not want to have to write 5 new methods for each repository which will just go on to call the methods of this generic repository.

Is there a simple solution to this problem or is this an acceptable use of inheritance and an unavoidable drawback that comes with inheriting DI-registered services?

Comment: Do get rid of all of your `catch (Exception ex)` blocks. It's an awful anti-pattern. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. Otherwise it leads to sloppy programming. I would reject all of this code if I were doing a code review.

Comment: Get rid of your repositories too, they are also an antipattern. Directly use DbContext instances which actually implement a proper unit of work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have these try-catch blocks as I planned on adding some exception logging once I found a solution to these problems but I agree at this point they are useless. And getting rid of my repositories and replacing them with a DbContext assumes I am using an Entity Framework which I am not. Or am I missing something there?

Comment: @kj49 - Please make separate replies to each message and use the `@` notification system to get the attention of the person you're replying to.

Comment: @kj49 - Your current exception handlers are not just useless, they are harmful as they swallow your exceptions. If you're going to put in placeholder exception handling then use an exception that is utterly impossible to get thrown, like `DriveNotFoundException`. Then you can easily go back and find all of the exception handling you need to work on, but they won't affect your code in the meanwhile.

Comment: @TanveerBadar It's not an antipattern. By using DbContext directly, your design will be tightly coupled to EF. You can't change ORM easily. You can't write tests easily. It will be hell. Don't use DbContext as a unit of work. It's usually better to use your unit of work wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

> A big problem I see here is that I will have to pass the inherited class' constructor parameters manually using base() and therefore every child class will have to know about its parent's dependencies.

Yes, that's how inheritance works in C# (and all other languages I know well enough to compare it to). If a base class *depends* on something, that dependency doesn't vanish when another class inherits from it.

So either you live with that, or you consider another design.

> I chose inheritance over simply injecting an instance of the generic repository because I do not want to have to write 5 new methods for each repository which will just go on to call the methods of this generic repository.

Given the currently stated requirements, I understand the reasoning. It's not wrong if the *only* alternative you consider is injecting a CRUD service into other services that then have to wrap and expose those five methods.

There *are* plenty of other options, however. Here are just a few, but surely, if I knew more about the specific context, I could think of several other.

## Keep services separate

An implicit assumption in the OP seems to be that there should be only one repository per `T`. Only one `GeneralRepository<TaskModel>`, only one `GeneralRepository<Foo>`, only one `GeneralRepository<Bar>`, and so on.

Another alternative is to define a CRUD interface `IGeneralRepository<T>` and implement it in a single `sealed` class.

Let's say, then, that you have a class that needs more methods than the four exposed by `IGeneralRepository<T>`. Let's call that class `TaskModelController`. If so, define another interface `ITaskModelExtra` and inject that *in addition to* `IGeneralRepository<TaskModel>`:

```
public TaskModelController(
    IGeneralRepository<TaskModel> crud,
    ITaskModelExtra extra)
{
    // ...
```

I don't insist that this is better, but since I don't know the specific context, I can't say that it's worse, either. I only suggest this to illustrate that there are other ways to slice the cake.

## Use an ORM

In general, [I'm not fond of object-relational mappers](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/10/23/domain-model-first) (ORMs), but then again I usually don't write CRUD-intensive applications. Since the OP context is specifically a CRUD-based application, using an ORM seems like a good idea. It's that kind of application that ORMs are designed to address.

Don't reinvent the wheel with a generic repository. You can easily do a web search of *"generic repository pattern bad"* if you want to learn more about why this is generally regarded as a bad idea. ([Not invented here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome is a big part of it.)

## SOLID

> I want to follow SOLID

This isn't that easy to do with a CRUD-heavy application, and the question is also whether it's warranted. Ask yourself *why* you want to follow SOLID.

[APPP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp) only explains what SOLID is *after* outlining the problems (design smells) that it addresses: Rigidity, fragility, immobility, viscosity, needless complexity, needless repetition, and opacity.

Do you have, or do you foresee having, these problems? How do you think that SOLID is going to address those concerns in your particular context?

In particular, does the proposed design follow the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)?

## Details

A few other details about the suggested code warrants comments.

If `GeneralRepository<T>` is to serve as a base class, then why does it implement an interface (`IGeneralRepository<T>`). What purpose does the interface have?

I'm assuming that the `IGeneralRepository<T>` interface only defines the five CRUD methods, so for any class that needs more capabilities (like my hypothetical `TaskModelController`, above) you'll need to address that need.

If, after all this, you decide to stick with an inheritance-based design, make the base class proper polymorphic. Make the five methods `virtual` so that you can `override` their behaviour in test, and ditch the interface.

Another concern: Why inject `IConfiguration` into `GeneralRepository<T>`? The code only uses it to get the connection string.

The [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) says that a class should only depend on the members it needs. There's no need for `GeneralRepository<T>` to be tightly coupled to `IConfiguration` when all it needs is a `string`.

Comment: I passed IConfiguration instead of just a string as it allows me to utilize dependency injection to feed my app settings to any repository that needs it. I agree that an ORM would make my life a lot easier, but I am creating this project to improve my software skills, and I think opting for an ORM is a missed opportunity to do that. I also thought that creating an interface for my base class would allow me to add that same interface to any repositories that inherit from it, thus exposing those methods once I check that repository into dependency injection. I will look into adding virtuals.